# How can I return data in Blocking code of vertx

Tags: java, vert.x

for example:

```
public Future<String> test() {
    Future<String> future = Future.succeededFuture();

    return vertx.createSharedWorkerExecutor("test")
        .executeBlocking(y -> {
            return future.map("Something");
        })
        .compose(x -> {
            return future;
        });
}
```

I want to return String in Blocking code,but it always return null.

Comment: Don't you just need `return future.map("Something");`?

Comment: you mean return future.map("Sth") in outside? In fact,I want to generate some data in executeBlocking ,  then return it , if i  return future in outside,it will be null

Comment: @Druckles and i can do that in nonblocking way;```
         Future<String> future1 = Future.succeededFuture();
        System.out.println(future1.compose(x -> {
            return Future.succeededFuture("hello");
        }).result());```

Comment: you shall NOT define your future as `succeeded`.Just put `future = Future.future()`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define `Future` externally, as you do now.

In your code, `y` is already a `Promise` (next version of `Future`)

Your code could be simplified to:

```java
public Future<String> test() {
    return vertx.createSharedWorkerExecutor("test")
        .executeBlocking(future -> {
            return future.complete("Something");
        });
}
```